# script to auto-update version of packages in package.json

Tags: package.json, npm-package

I manage a custom `npm` repository with several packages dependent each other.
When I modify a package (A), I updated its version. At this point, I should update all its references in other packages (B,C) to let them download the new version. Indeed, those packages (B,C) that use the new version, needs a new version number them too.

for instance:

```
@mypackage.A = 1.0.0
@mypackage.B = 1.0.0 (uses mypackage.A@1.0.0)
@mypackage.C = 1.0.0 (uses mypackage.A@1.0.0)
@mypackage.D = 1.0.0 (doesn't use mypackage.A)
```

Than I update `@mypackage.A` to `1.0.1`

```
    @mypackage.A = 1.0.1
    @mypackage.B = 1.0.0 (should use mypackage.A@1.0.1)
    @mypackage.C = 1.0.0 (should use mypackage.A@1.0.1)
    @mypackage.D = 1.0.0 (doesn't use mypackage.A)
```

So I update its reference in other packages, updating them too

```
    @mypackage.A = 1.0.1
    @mypackage.B = 1.0.1 (uses mypackage.A@1.0.1)
    @mypackage.C = 1.0.1 (uses mypackage.A@1.0.1)
    @mypackage.D = 1.0.0 (doesn't use mypackage.A)
```

How could I automate this? I need a script that, if I update `@mypackage.A` to `1.0.1`, it search in all the `package.json` of the other packages if there is a reference to A.
If there is, update it and increment the version of that package. At this point the same process should be recursively done of that package.

What can be used to do this? Grunt? Bash? Is there any specific package management techniques to do this?

---

Or, is there a way to let `package.json` using always the last version of a package?

Comment: I believe there are at the very least software out there or even features within npm that can do this for you, I would search for "npm dependency manager"

Comment: ok thank you. It would be easy to write a script doing that, but I’d like to use something more ‘professional’. I’ll search what you proposed

Comment: Good luck. When you figure it out, please post your answer here so it might help someone else :)